# Android Sherlock ActionBar date

Tags: android, date, actionbarsherlock

When I didn't install [Android Sherlock ActionBar](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). I had date in my ActionBar. This was a code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
String dateString = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd", new java.util.Date());
actionBar.setTitle(dateString);
```

Now when I have Sherlock I can not use this code because it does not work. How can I set date  Sherlock ActionBar?

Comment: You can do that with abs -> see the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `getSupportActionBar()` when you have ABS library implemented in your project!

[ABS Library Usage](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html)

Comment: What downvote is this?? Really i cant understand those guys who just downvote without letting you know what you did wrong...

Comment: I'm not the downvoter and do not know the library, but my guess would be that this answer doesn't explain why `getSupportActionBar()` is the proper function.

Comment: The OP clearly states that he uses ActionBar Sherlock library and his code isnt working anymore! So i answered and told him what is the right function to use when he has ABS implemented!!

Comment: That's so obvious... you use abs to support the older version. if you don't use the support lib it is a waste of effort. And more this answer is good.

Comment: Alright, like I said it was a guess and I'm not familiar with the library.  Maybe add a link or something?

Comment: Added above on my answer

Comment: I added Libary when I added ActionBar. I implemented getSupport method. The code: `    public com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
     ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
     String dateString = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd", new java.util.Date());
     actionBar.setTitle(dateString);
  return null;
 }` still does not work

Comment: No you shouldnt Override it! Just call it like this: ActionBar aBar = getSupportActionBar();

Comment: Pavlos is absolutely right , whenever we import ActionBarSherlock ,allways remember to add "Support"to yor function name for example        getActionBar()==>getSupportActionBar()  getFragment()==>getSupportFragment().